# Does scala provide anything like C++ templates?

Tags: c++, scala, templates, generics

I'm coming from C++ and trying to wrap my head around scala's type system.

Consider the following C++ template class:

```
template<class T>
class Point2
{
  Point2( T x, T y ) :
     x(x),
     y(y)
  {}

  T x;
  T y;
  Point2<T> operator+( Point<T> const& other ) const
  {
     return Point<T>(x+other.x, y+other.y);
  }
  T sumComponents() const { return x+y; }
}

Point2<Double> p0(12.3, 45.6) 
Point2<Double> p1(12.3, 45.6) 
Point2<Double> p = p1+p2
Double d = p1.sumComponents()
```

I'm finding I want to write something like this:

```
case class Point2[ T ] (x:T, y:T) {
   def +() Point2[T]: = x+y
   def sumComponents() T: = x+y
}
```

or, (because the compile has problems with this),

```
trait Addable[T] {   // Require T supports the + operatory
   def +( that:T ):T
}
case class Point2[ T<:Addable[T] ] (x:T, y:T) {
   def +() Point2[T]: = x+y
   def sumComponents() T: = x+y
}
```

which is similarly problematic because I can't require Double to extend Addable.

Generally, I'm finding it scala's type system works with a set of constraints that I don't quite understand.

What's the idiomatic way of implementing the above in scala?

And what's the right way for C++ template programmers to understand the limits of generics in scala? (*why* can't I do this in scala? e.g. Is it because generics are compiled before being instaniated?)

Comment: While Scala, being a large and eclectic language, might provide something similar to C++ templates, the accepted mainstream solution for your problem is "type classes". As they say, when in Rome do as Romans do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a library [template.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/template.scala). You can use the library to create C++ flavored templates, avoiding complicated `implicit`s.

```
import com.thoughtworks.template
case class Point2[T](x:T, y:T) {
   @template def +(rhs: Point2[_]) = Point2(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y)
   @template def sumComponents() = x + y
}

println(Point2(1, 3).sumComponents()) // Output: 4
println(Point2(1, 3) + Point2(100, 200)) // Output: Point2(101,203)
```

Note that you can even plus two `Point2`s with different component types.

```
println(Point2(1.5, 0.3) + Point2(100, 200)) // Output: Point2(101.5,200.3)
```

Even nested `Point2`:

```
// Output: Point2(Point2(10.1,20.2),Point2(101.0,202.0))
println(Point2(Point2(0.1, 0.2), Point2(1.0, 2.0)) + Point2(Point2(10, 20), Point2(100, 200)))
```

It works because `@template` functions are code templates that will inline at the call site.

Comment: You might have a very good library but it's is a pretty bad answer because it doesn't explain how the library works.

Comment: @n.m. It works because `@template` functions are code templates that will inline at the call site.

Comment: This should be a part of the answer.

Comment: It is now.
Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Any updates on this? Did it anything like it make it into scala?

Comment: `template.scala` is a library that you can use right now.

Answer (score 17):

> What's the idiomatic way of implementing the above in scala?

Either by specifying appropriate requirements of `T`, or using type classes to provide the desired behavior. I'll get back to this later.

> And what's the right way for C++ template programmers to understand
>   the limits of generics in scala? (why can't I do this in scala? e.g.
>   Is it because generics are compiled before being instaniated?)

C++ templates are compiled "at" the usage site, and different code is generated for each combination of parameters to the templates. So if you use the class above with `int` and `double`, you get two different `Point2` classes compiled.

Basically, C++ templates are macros, though nowhere near as dumb as `#define` macros. In fact, C++ templates are turing complete. Maybe it will be possible to accomplish something equivalent in the future, with the upcoming macro capabilities planned for Scala 2.11 and beyond, but let's ignore that for now.

Type parameters (Scala equivalent of Java *generics*) do not change how a code is compiled. A parameterized class generates its bytecode when it is compiled, not when it is used. So, by the time one instantiates a `Point2` with `Double`, it is too late to generate bytecode.

That means that *the code generated by a parameterized class must be compatible with all types a class can be instantiated with*.

And that's the source of the trouble: any methods called on `T` must be known to be present on `T` at the time `Point2` is compiled. Therefore, `T` must be defined to have an upper boundary of traits or classes that define such methods, as you have shown in your example.

Of course, that is not always possible, as you rightly pointed out, and that's where type classes come in. A type class is a set of types for which a set of behaviors is defined. Type classes, as implemented in Scala, are defined as classes whose instances define the behavior of other classes.

In the example you gave, you'd be using either the `Numeric` type class, or the `Fractional` type class if you need fractional division as well. A simple example of type class use is:

```
scala> import scala.math.Numeric
import scala.math.Numeric

scala> def sum[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = num.plus(x, y)
sum: [T](x: T, y: T)(implicit num: scala.math.Numeric[T])T
```

Or, using a special notation called "context bounds",

```
scala> def sum[T : Numeric](x: T, y: T): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)
sum: [T](x: T, y: T)(implicit evidence$1: scala.math.Numeric[T])T
```

The notation `T : Numeric` can be read as *`T` such that there's an implicit instance of `Numeric[T]`* available. The code `implicitly[X]` returns an implicit value of type `X` if one can be found (or fails at compile time).

Now, notice how no method is called on `x` and `y` -- instead, we call methods on `num` whose class is `Numeric[T]`. The class `Numeric[T]` has a method `plus` which knows how to add two `T`s.

Because what we need is type class instances, one can easily add new types to satisfy a type class. One could easily declare a `Numeric` type class for `Point2` (assuming all its methods could be implemented):

```
class Point2Numeric[T](implicit num: Numeric[T]) extends Numeric[Point2[T]] {
  def plus(x: Point2[T], y: Point2[T]): Point2[T] = x + y
  // etc
}
implicit def ToPoint2Numeric[T : Numeric] = new Point2Numeric[T]
```

With that in place, then for any `T` for which there's a `Numeric[T]`, there would be also a `Numeric[Point2[T]]`.

After plain type inheritance (upper type bounds), type classes are the most common form of type constraint used in Scala. There are other forms a bit more sophisticated, for which there's some discussion whether they are type classes or something different -- the magnet pattern, for instance. Look at [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for an example of how far one can take such things.

Another kind of type constraint that used to be very common but is now being used more circumspectly are *view bounds*. I'll not go into details (in fact, search for context bounds and view bounds to find a long answer about it from myself), but they can be used to make type classes more readable when used. For example:

```
scala> import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

scala> def sum[T : Numeric](x: T, y: T): T = x + y
sum: [T](x: T, y: T)(implicit evidence$1: scala.math.Numeric[T])T
```

The imported definitions contain implicit conversions that make it possible to use values of type `T` for which there's a `Numeric[T]` as if they, themselves, had the methods like `+` or `-`.

As a final note, it is important to realize this goes through many levels of indirection and, therefore, might not be very suitable for high performance code.

Comment: "Basically, C++ templates are macros" Scheme macros, which are almost unrelated with `#define` macros.

Comment: @pedrofurla I'm directing the answer to a C++ public, for whom "macros" will usually equate to defines.

Comment: Beware: you used the term "view bound" where you really meant "context bounds"

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I've used it three times, and I meant "view bound" in all tree, though I admit my usage for the last one isn't usual. On (`Numeric.Implicits`)[http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric$$Implicits$], there's an implicit conversion that makes `T`, for which there's a `Numeric` context bound, to be _viewable as `Ops`_. I'll reword to something clearer.

Comment: Oh, my bad. The confusion came from the fact that you say "they can be used to make type classes more readable when used" and then your example shows a context bound, whose main purpose is certainly to provide syntactic sugar to "make type classes more readable". I guess I've read that too fast and overlooked the fact that you were actually focusing on `x + y`. Sorry again.

Comment: "In fact, C++ templates are turing complete. Maybe it will be possible to accomplish something equivalent in the future" That future is now. Scala implicit  resolution is also Turing-complete as well as Scala macro system available since Scala 2.10. Also Scala macro system is nowhere near as limited as C++ templates - it can do arbitrary AST transformations / code generation, not just in-place blind symbol substitution. C++ templates are still much closer to old #defines than to Scheme or Scala macros.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, you can do something like this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import math.Numeric
import math.Numeric.Implicits._

case class Point2[A: Numeric](x: A, y: A) {
  def + (other: Point2[A]): Point2[A] =
    Point2(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y)

  def sumComponents: A = x + y
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import math.Numeric
import math.Numeric.Implicits._
defined class Point2

scala> val p1 = Point2(1, 2)
p1: Point2[Int] = Point2(1,2)

scala> val p2 = Point2(3, 4)
p2: Point2[Int] = Point2(3,4)

scala> p1 + p2
res2: Point2[Int] = Point2(4,6)

scala> val p3 = Point2(1.2, 3.4)
p3: Point2[Double] = Point2(1.2,3.4)

scala> val p4 = Point2(1.6, 6.4)
p4: Point2[Double] = Point2(1.6,6.4)

scala> p3 + p4
res3: Point2[Double] = Point2(2.8,9.8)

scala>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Numeric`, available as an `implicit`.

```
import scala.math.Numeric;
case class Point2[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T])
```

Look at `Numeric` [in the API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric), does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a type class (which I'm calling `Addition`) and an implicit conversion (which I'm defining via an implicit class called `Op`). In practice, you would use the `Numeric` type for this particular situation, but for the purpose of illustration, this is how you would define your own:

```
trait Addition[T] {

  def add(a: T, b: T): T

  implicit class Op(a: T) { 
    def +(b: T) = add(a, b)
  }
}

implicit object IntAddition extends Addition[Int] {
  def add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

implicit object DoubleAddition extends Addition[Double] {
  def add(a: Double, b: Double) = a + b
}

case class Point2[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit addition: Addition[T]) {

  import addition.Op

  def +(p: Point2[T]): Point2[T] = Point2(x + p.x, y + p.y)
  def sumComponents(): T = x + y
}
```