# Scala : class[T] extends T?

Tags: java, scala, generics, inheritance

Question : How could I achieve the following pattern in scala or Java ?

```
trait A
case class B[Base](...) extends A with Base
```

this is allowed in C++ :

```
template <class Base>
class B : public Base, public A
```

---

Here is why I want to do it :

I have two abstract syntax trees :  `ComplexForm` and `SimpleForm`

and I have a type for lists : `case class L[T](list : List[T]) extends Complex Form with T`

now, `L[SimpleForm]` should `extends SimpleForm with ComplexForm`
but `L[ComplexForm]` should only `extend ComplexForm`

I need to be able to pattern match agains all `L[T]` at once in order to avoid duplication.

Comment: @cchantep, I obviously tried : `case class O[T](list: List[T]) extends T` and the error is "(1) T does not have a constructor; (2) class type required but T found"

Comment: generics works different than c++ templates, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347167/does-scala-provide-anything-like-c-templates

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve by mixing in an arbitrary `T`. Why would a wrapper `L[T]` also need to be a `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
trait Form
trait SimpleForm extends Form
trait ComplexForm extends Form
trait ListForm[+T <: Form] extends ComplexForm {
   def l: List[T]
}


case class SimpleList(val l: List[SimpleForm]) extends SimpleForm with ListForm[SimpleForm]
case class ComplexList(val l: List[ComplexForm]) extends ListForm[ComplexForm]
```

You can pattern match both like this:

```
 // ...
 case x:ListForm[Form] => doStuff(x.l)
```