# Use one recursive case class constructor in two sealed traits

Tags: scala, traits, case-class, algebraic-data-types

I am defining few ADTs representing logic formulas. They all use i.e. `And` constructor, but then differ in what other constructors they use. I'd like to reuse case class definitions with a hope that I could reuse some code later. I'd like to do something like:

```scala
sealed trait Formula
sealed trait PositiveFormula

case class Not(sub) extends Formula
case class And(left, right) extends Formula, PositiveFormula
```

But this doesn't work for any single type for `sub`, `left` and `right`.
So I'd like to say:

```scala
sealed trait Formula
sealed trait PositiveFormula

case class Not[A](sub : A)
Not[Formula] extends Formula
case class And(left : A, right : A)
And[Formula] extends Formula
And[PositiveFormula] extends PositiveFormula
```

A few questions:

1. Is anything like above possible and I just dont know syntax?
2. Is there other solution to "reuse case class constructors" problem?
3. What's your opinion on how useful this would be if possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, maybe describe it with words rather than some inexistent syntax?

Comment: Why do you need two different kinds of ADTs? Can't all of those share a single parent type?

Comment: It really is not clear what you are trying to do here, or even what the question actually means. For example, can you explain what you mean by a "recursive case class constructor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala parametric classes can't extend different parents for different type parameters (only parent's type parameter can vary).

It seems you want to have something like "`Not[T] extends T`", "`And[T] extends T`" (pseudocode). See [Scala : class[T] extends T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100317/scala-classt-extends-t)

You can try

```
sealed trait Formula
sealed trait PositiveFormula

trait NotLike[A] {
  def sub: A

  // your generic code here
}

case class Not(sub: Formula) extends NotLike[Formula] with Formula

trait AndLike[A] {
  def left: A
  def right: A

  // your generic code here
}

case class And(left: Formula, right: Formula) extends 
  AndLike[Formula] with Formula

case class PositiveAnd(left: PositiveFormula, right: PositiveFormula) extends 
  AndLike[PositiveFormula] with PositiveFormula
```

You can also introduce `FormulaLike`, a common parent for `Formula` and `PositiveFormula`

```
sealed trait FormulaLike
sealed trait Formula extends FormulaLike
sealed trait PositiveFormula extends FormulaLike

trait NotLike[A <: FormulaLike] {
  def sub: A
}

trait AndLike[A <: FormulaLike] {
  def left: A
  def right: A
}
```

[Is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `PositiveFormula` a `Formula` or not? Just in case, if so then you can make `PositiveFormula` extend `Formula` (instead of introducing `FormulaLike`).

Or maybe you can try to express your relations between types with type classes (inheritance can be too restrictive, composition should be preferred over inheritance)

https://www.baeldung.com/scala/type-classes (intro to type classes)

https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-1/ (one more intro to type classes)

https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html (type classes and F-bounds)

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/nat.scala (example of type-level calculations with type classes)

You can have hierarchy of classes (nodes) extending `Formula` and mark some of the nodes as belonging to the type class `IsPositive`

```
// hierarchy
sealed trait Formula
  
// type class
trait IsPositive[A <: Formula]

case class Not[A <: Formula](sub: A) extends Formula
  
case class And[A <: Formula](left: A, right: A) extends Formula
implicit def and[A <: Formula](implicit ev: IsPositive[A]): IsPositive[And[A]] = null
```

or use [phantom types](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:labelled-generic:type-tagging) with type classes

```scala
// phantom types
type Formula
type PositiveFormula /*<: Formula*/

case class Not[A](sub: A)
case class And[A](left: A, right: A)
    
// type class
trait NotTypeclass[A] {
  type Out
  def apply(sub: A): Out
}

object NotTypeclass {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = NotTypeclass[A] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[A, Out0](f: A => Out0): Aux[A, Out0] = new NotTypeclass[A] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(sub: A): Out0 = f(sub)
  }

  implicit def not[A <: Formula]: Aux[A, Not[A] with Formula] =
    instance(sub => Not(sub).asInstanceOf[Not[A] with Formula])
}

def makeNot[A](sub: A)(implicit notTc: NotTypeclass[A]): notTc.Out = notTc(sub)

// type class
trait AndTypeclass[A] {
  type Out
  def apply(left: A, right: A): Out
}

trait LowPriorityAnd {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = AndTypeclass[A] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[A, Out0](f: (A, A) => Out0): Aux[A, Out0] = new AndTypeclass[A] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(left: A, right: A): Out0 = f(left, right)
  }

  implicit def and[A <: Formula]: Aux[A, And[A] with Formula] =
    instance((l, r) => And(l, r).asInstanceOf[And[A] with Formula])
}
object AndTypeclass extends LowPriorityAnd {
  implicit def positiveAnd[A <: PositiveFormula]: Aux[A, And[A] with PositiveFormula] =
    instance((l, r) => And(l, r).asInstanceOf[And[A] with PositiveFormula])
}

def makeAnd[A](left: A, right: A)(implicit andTc: AndTypeclass[A]): andTc.Out =
  andTc(left, right)
```

```scala
makeAnd(??? : PositiveFormula, ???): PositiveFormula
makeAnd(??? : Formula, ???): Formula
makeNot(??? : Formula): Formula
// makeNot(??? : PositiveFormula) // doesn't compile

makeNot(makeAnd(??? : Formula, ???)): Formula
makeAnd(makeNot(??? : Formula), makeAnd(??? : Formula, ???)): Formula
makeAnd(makeAnd(??? : Formula, ???), makeAnd(??? : Formula, ???)): Formula
makeAnd(makeAnd(??? : PositiveFormula, ???), makeAnd(??? : PositiveFormula, ???)): PositiveFormula
```

or use phantom types keeping type classes only for type-level calculations

```
type Formula
type PositiveFormula /*<: Formula*/

case class Not[A](sub: A)
case class And[A](left: A, right: A)

trait NotTypeclass[A] {
  type Out
}
object NotTypeclass {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = NotTypeclass[A] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def not[A <: Formula]: Aux[A, Formula] = null
}

def makeNot[A](sub: A)(implicit
  notTc: NotTypeclass[A]
): Not[A] with notTc.Out = Not(sub).asInstanceOf[Not[A] with notTc.Out]

trait AndTypeclass[A] {
  type Out
}
trait LowPriorityAnd {
  type Aux[A, Out0] = AndTypeclass[A] {type Out = Out0}

  implicit def and[A <: Formula]: Aux[A, Formula] = null
}
object AndTypeclass extends LowPriorityAnd {
  implicit def positiveAnd[A <: PositiveFormula]: Aux[A, PositiveFormula] = null
}

def makeAnd[A](left: A, right: A)(implicit
  andTc: AndTypeclass[A]
): And[A] with andTc.Out = And(left, right).asInstanceOf[And[A] with andTc.Out]
```

or use phantom types without type classes

```
type Formula
type PositiveFormula /*<: Formula*/

case class Not[A](sub: A)
case class And[A](left: A, right: A)

def makeNot[A <: Formula](sub: A): Not[A] with Formula = 
  Not(sub).asInstanceOf[Not[A] with Formula]

def makeAnd[A <: Formula](left: A, right: A): And[A] with Formula =
  And(left, right).asInstanceOf[And[A] with Formula]
def makePositiveAnd[A <: PositiveFormula](left: A, right: A): And[A] with PositiveFormula =
  And(left, right).asInstanceOf[And[A] with PositiveFormula]
```

`Formula` and `PositiveFormula` are abstract types rather than traits to avoid `ClassCastException`.

Comment: thanks for many examples. i sort of knew the first solution is possible but im yet to evaluate how much repetitions does it save me

Answer (score 0):

You need types for case class fields. You can probably make `PositiveFormula` extend `Formula` too. For example, this would work for `Boolean` operands.

```
sealed trait Formula
sealed trait PositiveFormula extends Formula
case class Not(sub:Boolean) extends Formula
case class And(left:Boolean, right:Boolean) extends PositiveFormula
```